# Selenium click sometimes not working using Edge driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Please see pic below. I have tried to select the input tag through the following method using Selenium:

```
   1. `element.Click();`
   2. `element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);`
   3. Actions action = new Actions(Browser.Driver).MoveToElement(element);
        action.Click().Perform();
```

I am trying to click the checkbox by returning it through a property in code that has the following code:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            IWebElement checkbox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.CssSelector("label[for='PerformerIndependence_AcceptTermsAndConditions']"))));
            return checkbox;
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            IWebElement checkbox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.CssSelector("input#PerformerIndependence_AcceptTermsAndConditions"))));
            return checkbox;
```

For some reason If I run the code in debug mode to test the element returned to click it will click.  If I just run my test in run mode using Visual Studio2015, the checkbox is not clicked.  The method using the element to click for the three attempts is wrapped in a try/catch block. Please help!!!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrMaq.png)

Comment: Show `HTML` code for mentioned check-box

Comment: I had a problem with clicks, too. I just used JS to click it via Selenium's JavascriptExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue. Click on checkbox is not working in Edge..

There are two work around of this:

1. click using JS
2. use action class..

WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

==========================================================

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

Both worked fine in my case.

Comment: add some examples of the solutions mentioned above, it might help several other users.